# How to use Node Explorer for custom CordApp

Tags: corda

Is possible to use the Node explorer for a custom CordApp (even for local development)?

The instructions provided in the guide [Using the Node Explorer to test a Corda node on Corda Testnet](https://docs.corda.net/testnet-explorer-corda.html)
seem to be targeted to the corda-finance app only.

It would be really useful to use this tool instead of the shell, especially to connect to a remote CordApp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, the node explorer is not supporting any other corDapps besides corda-finance. However, we had worked with the Truffle team(external) building an all in one corDapp env. Give a try about this: https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/releases/tag/v2.3.0-beta.1